# Implementing access and refresh token refresh with identityserver3

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm trying to implement persistent access token usage on the client side and would love to hear about the right way to go about it.

Right now I have a wpf application working with an identityserver3 backend using code flow. I use a long lived refresh token.

My idea for keeping the access token alive is to check the expiration of the access token upon every request and under a specific value to do a refresh token.

Is this the optimal way to go about it?

Also what would be the optimal scenario for refresh token refreshing? Should I also monitor the expiration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer on the project git https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/358